# Prisma DB m-n relational database

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, prisma

I have 3 tables in my database
`Member`, `Characters` and `MemberCharacters`
1 member can have many `Characters` and 1 `Character` can be used by many `Members` 
To avoid the m to n relation, i use the `MemberCharacters` table that stores the memberId and the `characterIds` as foreign keys.
The tables look something like this:

```
model Members {
  id String @unique @id @default(cuid())
  displayName String
  characters MemberCharacters[]
}
model Characters {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
  pictureUrl String
  members MemberCharacters[]
}

model MemberCharacters {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  memberId String
  Members Members @relation(fields: [memberId], references: [id])
  characterId Int
  Characters Characters @relation(fields: [characterId], references: [id])
}
```

Now, i want a prisma request, that leads to me getting a json return containing all information about the `Member` and a list of the `Characters`, assigned to that `Member`.

In the [prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations), i found the option of using include. This almost does what i want except for one small thing - the result is a json containing all the Member information and a list of `MemberCharacter` json objects. However i need to get the actual `Character` objects, that the `MemberCharacter` is reffering to, information in that list.

```
let a = await prisma.members.findMany({
            include: {
                characters: true
            }
        })
        console.log(a)
```

Result:

```
{
        id: '86548974659889456',
        displayName: 'DisplayName',
        characters: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
}
```

On that same prisma docs page, there is also an approach that only uses two tables, but this doesn't work for me, since the data in Characters should not be changed, so using this, won't make my life easier neither.

```
model Post {
  id         Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  title      String
  categories Category[]
}

model Category {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String
  posts Post[]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a nested `include`. First you include the `MemberCharacters` then the actual `Characters`.

With your current schema, the query would look like this:

```js
prisma.members.findMany({
  include: { characters: { include: { Characters: true } } },
});
```

You can later on flatten the result of such a query:

```js
const members = await prisma.members.findMany({
  include: { characters: { include: { Characters: true } } },
});
const membersWithFlattendCharacters = members.map((member) => ({
  ...member,
  flattenedCharacters: member.characters.map(
    (memberCharacter) => memberCharacter.Characters
  ),
}));
```

As you can see, the naming is a bit confusing. I'd suggest to update the schema:

```
model Members {
  id               String @unique @id @default(cuid())
  displayName      String
  memberCharacters MemberCharacters[]
}
```

The query would then be:

```js
prisma.members.findMany({
  include: { memberCharacters: { include: { Characters: true } } },
});
```

Using singular names for the models would increase readability further...

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for your help. I will definitely have to update some naming.